# How to force the code to be executed inside the animate() function?

Tags: jquery, animation

In my situation.A slider show! I got several elements appended and removed by button click event in my animate() function.

I want to make a contents slider show.I thought:

make three div elements:

```
first:  <div class='pre'></div>
second: <div class='currentShow'>contents</div> this is default display contents
three:  <div class='next'></div>
```

and four link witch load contents:

```
<a class="btPanel" panel="1">1</a>
<a class="btPanel" panel="2">2</a>
<a class="btPanel" panel="3">3</a>
<a class="btPanel" panel="4">4</a>
```

so.when I first click content loads link, such as `"1"`, and then:

`div with class "next"` load the contents of "1", and then:

`div with class "pre"` animates the `div width attibute to "0"`,so the `div with class "currentShow"` slides to left and showing the contents inside the `div with class "next"`, and then:

I remove the `div with class "pre"` and make the `original div with class　“currentShow"` to be first div just like `"pre"`,clear the contents,remove the class and add class, and final:

append the `div with class "next"` to the end.so ,all the `html structure re-back the original and waiting for next slide.`

the problem is: when I quick switch the contents.such as click the link 1 ,2 ,3,4 one by one quickly. the append and remove and add class and remove class didn't finish the job so I got multi "contents" and "pre","next" div exist at the end.

But, when I click and quick switch the animation.The code inside the animate() function which want to remove element didn't execute and keep the element exist.So,Is there a way to force the code inside animate() function to be executed to the end!

html code:

```
<div style=" width:612px;  margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="" id="bt1" class="btPanel" panel="1" style="color:#FFF">panel 1</a>
    <a href="" id="bt2" class="btPanel" panel="2" style="color:#FFF">panel 2</a>
    <a href="" id="bt3" class="btPanel" panel="3" style="color:#FFF">panel 3</a>
    <a href="" id="bt4" class="btPanel" panel="4" style="color:#FFF">panel 4</a>
    <div id="igPanelWrap" style=" position:relative; height:30px; width:204px; overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto;">
        <div style=" position:absolute; width:612px;height:22px; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; left:-204px;" id="igPanel">
          <div style="width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider pre">empty</div>
          <div style="width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider currentShow ">2</div>
          <div style="width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider next">empty</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
    $('.btPanel').click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var panelNum = parseInt($(this).attr('panel'));

        if($('#igPanel .panelShow').length){

            var currentPanelNum = parseInt($('#igPanel .panelShow').attr('panelNum'));

            if(currentPanelNum === panelNum)
                return;

            if( currentPanelNum > panelNum){

                $('#igPanel .pre').
                   queue(function(next){
                      $(this).
                         html(panelNum).
                         addClass('panelShow').
                         removeClass('pre').
                         attr('panelNum',panelNum);
                         next();
                   }).
                   queue(function(next){
                      $('<div style="  width:0; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider pre">empty</div>').
                          prependTo('#igPanel').animate({width:200}, function(){
                              $('#igPanel .next').remove();
                              $('#igPanel .slider:last').
                                    html('empty').
                                    removeClass('panelShow').
                                    addClass('next').
                                    removeAttr('panelNum');
                          });
                      next();
                   });
            }
            else{

/*              $('#igPanel .next').html(panelNum).addClass('panelShow').removeClass('next').attr('panelNum',panelNum);
                $('#igPanel .pre').stop().animate({width:0}, function(){

                                        $(this).remove();
                                        $('#igPanel .slider:first').html('empty').removeClass('panelShow').addClass('pre').removeAttr('panelNum');
                                        $(' <div  style="width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider next">empty</div>').appendTo('#igPanel');
                                    });*/
                $('#igPanel .next').
                   queue(function(next){
                      $(this).
                         html(panelNum).
                         addClass('panelShow').
                         removeClass('next').
                         attr('panelNum',panelNum);
                         next();
                   }).
                   queue(function(next){

                      $('#igPanel .pre').animate({width:0}, function(){

                                        $(this).remove();
                                        $('#igPanel .slider:first').html('empty').removeClass('panelShow').addClass('pre').removeAttr('panelNum');
                                        $('<div  style="width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider next">empty</div>').appendTo('#igPanel');
                                    });
                      next();
                   });

            }
        }
        else{

            $('#igPanel .next').
               queue(function(next){
                  $(this).
                     html(panelNum).
                     addClass('panelShow').
                     removeClass('next').
                     attr('panelNum',panelNum);
                     next();
               }).
               queue(function(next){

                  $('#igPanel .pre').animate({width:0}, function(){

                                    $(this).remove();
                                    $('#igPanel .slider:first').html('empty').removeClass('panelShow').addClass('pre').removeAttr('panelNum');
                                    $('<div  style="width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider next">empty</div>').appendTo('#igPanel');
                                });
                  next();
               });
        }
/*      
        $('.panelShow').each(function(){

                        if($(this).attr('display') === 'undefined')
                            $(this).remove();
                                      });
*/                           
    });
```

thank you very much!!

Comment: You might want to explain what exactly is the problem and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, although I don't think this is the best way to be doing this, maybe look into a jQuery Carousel or something:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .btPanel{background:#F00}
            .slider{background:#00F; width:200px; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF; cursor:pointer}
            .next{}
            .currentShow{}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changePanel(thisObj, panel)
            {
                animateWidth = parseFloat($('.currentShow').width());

                $('.currentShow').addClass('pre').removeClass('currentShow');
                //$('.next').addClass('currentShow').removeClass('next');

                $('#igPanel').append('<div class="slider currentShow">'+loadContent(panel)+'</div>');
                $('.pre').stop(true,true).animate({'width':"-="+animateWidth+"px"}, function(){
                    $('.pre').detach();
                });
            }

            function loadContent(panel)
            {
                switch(panel)
                {
                    case 'panel1':
                        return "Some Content for Panel 1";
                    break;
                    case 'panel2':
                        return "This is Panel 2";
                    break;
                    case 'panel3':
                        return "Another Panel, this is 3";
                    break;
                    case 'panel4':
                        return "Finally this is Panel 4";
                    break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style=" width:612px;  margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;">
            <span class="btPanel" onClick="changePanel(this, 'panel1')">panel 1</span>
            <span class="btPanel" onClick="changePanel(this, 'panel2')">panel 2</span>
            <span class="btPanel" onClick="changePanel(this, 'panel3')">panel 3</span>
            <span class="btPanel" onClick="changePanel(this, 'panel4')">panel 4</span>
            <div id="igPanelWrap" style=" position:relative; height:30px; width:204px; overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto;">
                <div style=" position:absolute; width:612px;height:22px; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;" id="igPanel">
                  <div class="slider currentShow">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your idea is interesting. I will try it later!